# How to copy files containing the given character using terminal in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, command, command-line-interface

In Linux Mint, I have a directory that has many files and I want to copy files that contain `x` in their filename and paste them into other destination.

How can I do it using a terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the directory that contains all of your files, then try this one. this commnad can help you.

```
find . -name '*x*' -exec cp "{}" YourDestination  \;
```

replace `YourDestination` wtih every where you want.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is copying files one by one. You should either use `{} +` or combine `find` with `xargs`.

```sh
find . -name '*x*' -exec cp '{}' '+' YourDestination \;
```

```sh
find . -name '*x*' -print0 |
  xargs -0 sh -c 'cp "$@" your_destination' sh
```